# Task Manager for Firefox (like in Chrome?)

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, task-manager

I was looking over Chrome and the task manager feature and really wishing something like this was in Firefox (as i have lots of addons [probably too many] and lots of tabs open). I looked for an addon or something but perhaps I have missed something? Anyone know of something like Chrome's task manager but for FF?

Comment: I need that to clear the RAM. Tab unloaders do not work. Chrome task manager is *highly useful,* so Firefox just needs it.

Comment: Type this into your address bar in Firefox: "about:performance" (without quotes).

Comment: For Firefox 75 they have this option built-in to the menu. https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/task-manager-tabs-or-extensions-are-slowing-firefox

Answer (score 21):

There's a couple things you can do to see what kind of overhead you've imposed on Firefox.

The [`about:addons-memory`](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/about-addons-memory/) Extension will give you a nice looking page showing how much memory each of your extensions is using.  You can use that information to decide if the overhead imposed is worth the functionality it provides, or if you should look for a more lightweight extension that has similar functionality.

Also, the `about:memory` page will give you a very technical view of how Firefox is using the memory that's been allocated.

Be careful though, both views give fairly technical information and can be easily misleading if you don't truly understand what you're looking at, how memory allocation in Firefox works, and how your OS manages memory.

As far as I know Firefox doesn't have any built-in way to show the other details that Chrome's Task Manager does, like CPU and Network usage.  As @RobK alluded to, Firefox's current architecture may not make providing such statistics easy (or even possible).

Comment: about:addons-memory is currently broken for me(firefox 47). It hasn't been updated since 2014

Comment: Unfortunately, I can  not unload tabs. And the tab unloading add-ons are all bogus.

Answer (score 6):

Firefox does not have a task manager. Unfortunately, due to Firefox's architecture it would be difficult to monitor per-tab.

Comment: What about Quantum? (I do not like Quantum. But it works similarly to Chrome: seperate processes).

Answer (score 2):

There will not be any task manager in Firefox in the foreseeable future. Firefox now feature the [Firefox Health Report](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-health-report-understand-your-browser-perf).

Comment: Also read [Firefox uses too many CPU resources - How to fix](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-uses-too-many-cpu-resources-how-fix) and [Firefox is slow - How to make it faster](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-slow-how-make-it-faster)

Comment: Health report? Does that solve the problem? (no personal offence, but Health Report has nothing to do with task manager. I have still upvoted +1, because -1 stinks like armpit sweat). Still thanks for the answer. Maybe, things will change).